# SAS proc sort after appending to the dataset returns error

Tags: sas

I was appending a dataset to another, then sort the base dataset.

```
proc append base=&RAWDATA data=GAPDATA;
      run;
proc sort data=&RAWDATA; by Symbol Date Time; run;
```

But SAS keeps returning with the error message: ERROR: Indexed data set cannot be sorted in place unless the FORCE option is used.

The full code i used:

```
%MACRO GAP_SEC(RAWDATA);
  data GAPDATA;
    SET &RAWDATA;
    retain SYMBOL DATE TIME BB BO MIDPRICE;
    LAG_SYMBOL = lag(SYMBOL);
    LAG_DATE = lag(DATE);
    LAG_TIME = lag(TIME);
    LAG_BB = lag(BB);
    LAG_BO = lag(BO);
    LAG_MIDPRICE = lag(MIDPRICE);
    TIME_DIFF = intck('second', LAG_TIME, TIME);
    if TIME_DIFF > 1 and SYMBOL = LAG_SYMBOL and DATE = LAG_DATE then 
        DO;
            n=TIME_DIFF;
            TIME = LAG_TIME;
            DO WHILE(N>1);
              SYMBOL = LAG_SYMBOL;
              TIME = intnx('second',TIME,1);
              DATE = LAG_DATE;
              BB = LAG_BB;
              BO = LAG_BO;
              MIDPRICE = LAG_MIDPRICE;
              output;
              N=N-1;
            END;  
        END;
    drop LAG_SYMBOL LAG_DATE LAG_TIME LAG_BB LAG_BO LAG_MIDPRICE TIME_DIFF N;
  run;
  /* Add new obs to original data set */
  proc append base=&RAWDATA data=GAPDATA;
  run;
  proc sort data=&RAWDATA; by Symbol Date Time; run;
  proc export data=&RAWDATA (obs=99999)
    outfile= 'FILLEDDATA.csv'
    dbms=CSV REPLACE;
    putname=YES;
  run;  
%mend;
```

I was wondering what is the cause of such problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems clear:

ERROR: Indexed data set cannot be sorted in place unless the FORCE option is used.

You are sorting the dataset &rawdata. It sounds like an index is defined for that dataset.  You cannot sort the dataset in place. You can add an `out=` option to the PROC SORT to write an output dataset rather than sort in place. Or you could add the FORCE option. I don't know if that will remove the index or just make it less efficient.

Comment: I used the force option.